# Is it possible to write a method that returns a class object of T?

Tags: java, generics

If I have a base class such that

```
public abstract class XMLSubscription <T extends XMLMessage>
```

Is it possible to write a method in XMLSubscription that returns a class object of T?

The only possible solution that I came up with is to have each descendant of XMLSubscription have a method like:

```
public class XMLStatusSubscription extends XMLSubscription<XMLStatusMessage>
{
   public Class <XMLStatusMessage> getExpectedMessageType()
   {        
     return XMLStatusMessage.class;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you modify your question title to more reflect your generic question?  Like, can you specify a generic type that extends a class, or... something similar?  Someone searching for something similar to this is not going to be helped out by your question title.

Comment: Possibly "Can I return the Class type of a Java Generic?"

Comment: Good suggestions, I couldn't think of how to phrase the question, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately - and yes, this is due to type erasure - there is no way to return the `Class` object without providing it at runtime somehow.

Fortunately this is not usually too difficult.  Here's how I've typically done this / seen it done:

```
public abstract class XMLSubscription <T extends XMLMessage> {
    private Class<T> messageType;

    protected XMLSubscription(Class<T> messageType) {
        this.messageType = messageType;
    }

    public Class<T> getExpectedMessageType() {
        return this.messageType;
    }
}

public class XMLStatusSubscription extends XMLSubscription<XMLStatusMessage> {

    public XMLStatusSubscription() {
        super(XMLStatusMessage.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Your solution saves me a bit of code, and a lot of documentation/explanation! Nice work-around!

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, T is erased by the compiler. When you instantiate the object it has no idea that's it's supposed to deal with *XMLStatusMessage* objects. Your base class would define the following template method, and 1.5's covariant return types would keep the compiler happy with the concrete subclasses:

```
public Class<T> getExpectedMessageType()
```

There is one meta-comment: this looks a lot like procedural code, where something calls *getExpectedMessageType()* and then takes action based on the return type. This might be better implemented using a Visitor pattern, with the visitor implementing "doSomething" methods for each of the subclasses of *XMLMessage*.

Comment: To frame the question I had to cut out a lot of code and actually move stuff around. The actual code does implement a Visitor pattern like you recommend. The type is actually being passed into a Castor method so that it knows how to unmarshal to a Java object.